# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by выдает только в некоторых формах

Tags: php

Всем доброго времени суток!

Прошу сразу зайти на [мой GitHub](https://github.com/Lenskiy-e/Insurance), чтобы было понятней о чем я говорю.

Возникла такая штука, есть массив `data`, в котором хранятся шаблоны всех POST запросов, есть класс `message`, к которому подключен данный массив, класс обрабатывает POST запрос, а именно, создает файл с названием, взятым из POST запроса, вставляет в этот файл ключи и значения с массива `data`, если значение не пустое. После чего, через `Header('Location:')` переносить пользователя на другую страницу.

Есть 7 форм, с которых отправляются эти запросы. Собственно проблема: в формах, в которых есть предварительный калькулятор, а именно формы `ekspress_kvartira`, `osago`, `travel` все отлично работает, запросы принимает, инфу записывает в созданый файл.
Но вот запросы с других форм - фиг.

То есть, файл нормально создается, а вот не другую страницу не переносит. Выдает ошибку:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\site\Uniqa\components\post\data_list.php:37)

Перерыл все! Пробовал переписать класс, массив, смотрел формы, вроде бы одинаковый запрос отправляю, и все равно ничего не получается.
Прошу вас помочь, подсказать.
Буду очень благодарен!

---

Искал этот вопрос: пробелом и лишних знаков нету, изменение настройки apache не помогло.

Пример обработки, массив и обрабатывающий класс лежат в `/components/post`
Формы можно посмотреть `/views/forms`.

Comment: Всё перерывать не надо. Надо просто прочесть ошибку, в которой дано имя файла и номер строки, в которой происходит вывод.

Comment: Дело в том, что :
1. В похожих формах все нормально работает;
2. Оно выдает ошибку в той пере ключ-значение, где значение $_POST[] не передается.

Comment: Tо есть, перед этой ошибкой у тебя другая - Undefined index? Ну так тогда ее и надо исправлять!

Comment: Да, в этой форме выыводится всего 3 POST запроса из 37 в массиве. При этом, в других формах так же не заполняются все  POST запросы, но работает все хорошо.
Если есть время, можете посмотреть на моем GitHub формы:
/views/forms/Osago_form.php (которая работает) и /views/callback/Callback.php (при вызове которой выдает ошибку)

Comment: Еще раз. Ошибку Undefined index выдает или нет?

Comment: Да. Но о остальных формах тоже не все индексы есть, но там ошибки Cannot modify header information не выдает.

Comment: Ошибку Undefined index надо исправить

Comment: @EvgeniyLenskiy, все, что относится к вопросу, должно находится в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Comment: Ну и заодно http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/headers

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev, спасибо за ссылку. Все исправил.
Перенес header() в начало массива.

Comment: @EvgeniyLenskiy, т.е. вопрос исчерпан?

Comment: @ Dmitriy Simushev Да. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй добавить `ob_start();` в начало и `ob_get_contents();`в конец файла.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Проблема исправлена.

Comment: @EvgeniyLenskiy это не совет а костыль. Ошибки кода надо не залеплять пластырем на соплях, а исправлять. Чтобы они не вылезли где-то еще.

Comment: Не охота было подробно написать. Но раз уж это называете "костылем", давайте объясню. Header нельзя менять после отправления. Поэтому или нужно это делать до отправления, ИЛИ же как я указал выше, добавить все в буфер ob_start(); и в конце уже получить с помощью ob_get_contents();. Это как раз таки один из способов решения задачи.